# Views block for content that is older than current node created date

Tags: views, datetime

How should I go about creating a view that only shows content that is older than the current node's creation date? I've created the argument using 'Content: created date' but I struggle to pass this over to the filter criteria.

To be honest, I'm not even sure this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Looks like you have been struggling with this for a while now, Would you mind using some custom codes?

Comment: Hey saadlulu. I'll use anything as long as it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working with a Views PHP field:

```
<?php
global $base_path;

if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ! arg(2)) {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  $a1 = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'm/d/Y');
  $a2 = date("m/d/Y",strtotime("-2 months",strtotime($a1)));  
  $a3 = format_date($row->created, 'custom', 'm/d/Y');

  $b1 = new DateTime($a1);
  $b2 = new DateTime($a2);
  $b3 = new DateTime($a3);

  if ($b3 >= $b2 && $b3 <= $b1) {
    print '<h2><a href="'. $base_path . 'node/' . $row->nid . '">' . $row->title . '</a></h2>' . $data->field_body[0]['rendered']['#markup'];
    //dsm($data);
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a block which accepts the node created date as an argument. Then you'll need to set the condition to only show nodes which have a created date < the argument value.

To pass on the node's created date as an argument, I think it's easiest just to embed the View block into the node's template using a PHP snippet. So you'll be looking at something along the lines of:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('my_view','my_block_machine_name', $node->created); ?>
```

You might have to check for the correct variable name for the created date of the node, but I think "created" is correct.

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks AlexK. Managed to find a solution. Just posting now.